# Me lanza el siguiente error (0xC0000005) en C++

Tags: c++, matrices

```
struct Jugada {
    int origen, destino;
};

void show (const list<Jugada> & movimientos) {
    for (list<Jugada>::const_iterator it = movimientos.begin(); it != movimientos.end(); it++) {
        cout << it->origen << " -> " << it->destino << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

int getI (int ficha, int n) {
    return ficha / n;
}

int getJ (int ficha, int n) {
    return ficha - (ficha / n) * n;
}

int realizarMovimiento (int **pMatriz, int movimiento, int i, int j, int n, bool h) {
    pMatriz[i][j] = h;
    switch (movimiento) {
    case 0: /* arriba */
        pMatriz[i - 1][j] = h;
        pMatriz[i - 2][j] = !h;
        return j + i * n - 2 * n;
    case 1: /* derecha */
        pMatriz[i][j + 1] = h;
        pMatriz[i][j + 2] = !h;
        return j + i * n + 2;
    case 2: /* abajo */
        pMatriz[i + 1][j] = h;
        pMatriz[i + 2][j] = !h;
        return j + i * n + 2 * n;
    default: /* izquierda */
        pMatriz[i][j - 1] = h;
        pMatriz[i][j - 2] = !h;
        return j + i * n - 2;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool movimientoValido (int **pMatriz, int movimiento, int i, int j, int n) {
    if (pMatriz[i][j] == 1) {
        switch (movimiento) {
        case 0: /* 2 arriba */
            if (((j < 3 || j > 5) && i == 5) || i > 1) {
                return pMatriz[i-1][j] == 1 && pMatriz[i-2][j] == 0;
            }
        case 1: /* 2 derecha */
            if (((i < 3 || i > 5) && j == 3) || j < 7) {
                return pMatriz[i][j+1] == 1 && pMatriz[i][j+2] == 0;
            }
        case 2: /* 2 abajo */
            if (((j < 3 || j > 5) && i == 3) || i < 7) {
                return pMatriz[i+1][j] == 1 && pMatriz[i+2][j] == 0;
            }
        default: /* 2 izquierda */
            if (((i < 3 || i > 5) && j == 5) || j > 1) {
                return pMatriz[i][j-1] == 1 && pMatriz[i][j-2] == 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int back_senku (int **pMatriz, int n, int cantidad, list<Jugada> & pasos) {
    /* n inicializado con el tamaño de la matriz */
    /* cantidad inicializado con el cantidad total de fichas */
    /* pasos se guardan los todos los movimientos que permiten llegar a la solucion */
    if (cantidad == 1 && pMatriz[4][4] == 1) {
        show(pMatriz, n);
        show(pasos);
        return 1;
    } else {
        int solucion = 0;
        for (int ficha = 0; ficha < n * n && solucion == 0; ficha++) {
            for (int movimiento = 0; movimiento < 4 && solucion == 0; movimiento++) {
                int i = getI(ficha, n), j = getJ(ficha, n);
                if (movimientoValido(pMatriz, movimiento, i, j, n)) {
                    int v = realizarMovimiento(pMatriz, movimiento, i, j, n, 0);
                    Jugada jugada = {ficha, v};
                    pasos.push_back(jugada);
                    solucion = back_senku(pMatriz, n, cantidad - 1, pasos);
                    pasos.pop_back();
                    realizarMovimiento(pMatriz, movimiento, i, j, n, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        return solucion;
    }
}
```

Me lanza el error:

> 0xC0000005

y la verdad que nose a que se debe. Ya intente debugearlo paso a paso y no me logro dar cuenta. Ademas de que no se que significa el error. El codigo ejecuta lo mas bien, el error lo tira despues de una cierta cantidad de pasos. La idea es intentar resolver el juego del senku.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: El error que indicas es un "*Access Violation*", que generalmente sucede al intentar leer/escribir en memoria que no le corresponde a tu programa.

Comment: Puede ser debido a que el programa se este saliendo del rango de la matriz?

Comment: El intentar acceder a una posición que no esté disponible en la matriz es un candidato muy claro, efectivamente.

Answer (score 0):

```
    struct Jugada {
    int origen, destino;
};

void show (const list<Jugada> & movimientos) {
    for (list<Jugada>::const_iterator it = movimientos.begin(); it != movimientos.end(); it++) {
        cout << it->origen << " -> " << it->destino << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

int getI (int ficha, int n) {
    return ficha / n;
}

int getJ (int ficha, int n) {
    return ficha - (ficha / n) * n;
}

void realizarMovimiento (int **pMatriz, int movimiento, int i, int j, int n, bool h, int & v) {
    pMatriz[i][j] = h;
    if (movimiento == 0) {
        pMatriz[i - 1][j] = h;
        pMatriz[i - 2][j] = !h;
        v = j + i * n - 2 * n;
    } else if (movimiento == 1) {
        pMatriz[i][j + 1] = h;
        pMatriz[i][j + 2] = !h;
        v = j + i * n + 2;
    } else if (movimiento == 2) {
        pMatriz[i + 1][j] = h;
        pMatriz[i + 2][j] = !h;
        v = j + i * n + 2 * n;
    } else if (movimiento == 3) {
        pMatriz[i][j - 1] = h;
        pMatriz[i][j - 2] = !h;
        v = j + i * n - 2;
    }
}

bool movimientoValido (int **pMatriz, int movimiento, int i, int j, int n) {
    if (movimiento == 0) {
        if (((j <= 2 || j >= 6) && i == 5) || (j > 2 && j < 6 && i >= 2)) {
            return pMatriz[i - 1][j] == 1 && pMatriz[i - 2][j] == 0;
        }
    } else if (movimiento == 1) {
        if (((i <= 2 || i >= 6) && j == 3) || (i > 2 && i < 6 && j <= 6)) {
            return pMatriz[i][j + 1] == 1 && pMatriz[i][j + 2] == 0;
        }
    } else if (movimiento == 2) {
        if (((j <= 2 || j >= 6) && i == 3) || (j > 2 && j < 6 && i <= 6)) {
            return pMatriz[i + 1][j] == 1 && pMatriz[i + 2][j] == 0;
        }
    } else if (movimiento == 3) {
        if (((i <= 2 || i >= 6) && j == 5) || (i > 2 && i < 6 && j >= 2)) {
            return pMatriz[i][j - 1] == 1 && pMatriz[i][j - 2] == 0;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int back_senku (int **pMatriz, int n, int cantidad, list<Jugada> & pasos) {
    /* n inicializado con el tamaño de la matriz */
    /* cantidad inicializado con el cantidad total de fichas */
    /* pasos se guardan los todos los movimientos que permiten llegar a la solucion */
    if (cantidad == 1 && pMatriz[4][4] == 1) {
        show(pMatriz, n);
        show(pasos);
        return 1;
    } else {
        int solucion = 0;
        for (int ficha = 0; ficha < n * n && solucion == 0; ficha++) {
            int i = getI(ficha, n), j = getJ(ficha, n);
            if (pMatriz[i][j] == 1) {
                for (int movimiento = 0; movimiento < 4 && solucion == 0; movimiento++) {
                    if (movimientoValido(pMatriz, movimiento, i, j, n)) {
                        int v = 0;
                        realizarMovimiento(pMatriz, movimiento, i, j, n, 0, v);
                        Jugada jugada = {ficha, v};
                        pasos.push_back(jugada);
                        solucion = back_senku(pMatriz, n, cantidad - 1, pasos);
                        pasos.pop_back();
                        realizarMovimiento(pMatriz, movimiento, i, j, n, 1, v);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return solucion;
    }
}
```

Ya lo solucione!
Gracias!